# Converting an array of objects (with string array elements) into a nested tree

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to solve a problem with arrays and objects for some time now - but I still can't find the right solution.

This is my starting position:

```
list = [
{
    lastItemData: {data:"root"},
    path: ["Root"]
},
{
    lastItemData: {data:"level2_Summer"},
    path: ["Root", "Level2_Summer"]
},
{
    lastItemData: {data:"Level3_Monday"},
    path: ["Root", "Level2_Winter", "Level3_Monday"]
},
{
    lastItemData: {data:"Level4_Morning"},
    path: ["Root", "Level2_Spring", "Level3_Tuesday", "Level4_Morning"]
},
{
    lastItemData: {data:"Level3_Sunday"},
    path: ["Root", "Level2_Autumn", "Level3_Sunday"]
}]
```

and this is what i need:

```
result = [
{
    text: "Root",
    lastItemData: {data:"root"},
    Items:[
        {
            text:"Level2_Summer",
            lastItemData: {data:"level2_Summer"},
            Items: []
        },
        {
            text:"Level2_Winter",
            Items:[
                {
                    text: "Level3_Monday",
                    lastItemData: {data:"Level3_Monday"},
                    Items: []
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text:"Level2_Spring",
            Items:[
                {
                    text: "Level3_Tuesday"
                    Items: [
                        {
                            text:"Level4_Morning"
                            Items:[],
                            lastItemData: {data:"Level4_Morning"},
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text:"Level2_Autumn",
            Items:[
                {
                    text: "Level3_Sunday"
                }
            ]
        },
    ]
}]
```

I'v try something like this (code is based on user jonas answer from my deleted post)

```
const property = list.reduce((previous, current, index) => {


            let acc = {}; //the accumulator that will go deep into the object
            const result = acc; //our result will be the top level object

            debugger;

            //Now we iterate over our array
            for (var i = 0; i < current.stringPath.length; i++) {
                debugger;
                //add the string part
                acc["level" + (i + 1)] = current.stringPath[i];
                //Add the children array
                acc["Items"] = [{}];
                //And go into the object
                acc = acc["Items"][0];
            }

            console.log(result)

            previous.push(result);

            return previous;

        }, []);

        console.log("property", property);
```

But unfortunately the result does not correspond to the desired structure. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Why would you delete a post about the same topic that already has an answer? This is rude towards the person that spent time answering you.

Comment: @Tomalak: Indeed, if it was the OP that deleted it rather than the community. Isabelle - If appropriate, you can find the previous post by going to [your profile > Activity > Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3736673/isabelle-diez?tab=questions), scrolling to the bottom, and clicking [deleted recent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/recently-deleted-questions/3736673) (I think that's the right link), undelete it, and then either ask for clarification on existing answers to it (and delete this question) or, if this is a new question, link to that question in the text.

Comment: That does not show up for me, unfortunately.

Comment: I asked the question last time - but it was not very clear, the formatting of the code was wrong and in general unclear. One user asked me to delete the question and ask it again. What i did. But there was no solution to the question. Otherwise, I wouldn't ask the same question twice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a far more complex problem as it looks like, because you have to build a nested structure with a given name (`text` property) and you need to check if that name exist or not. If not create a new object and push it to the parent array.

This solution features a hash table where all nested hashes for each level are collected and maintained. The result is an array with the wanted tree.

It works as follows:

First have a look into the root of the hash table and check if the path value exists. If not, create a new node with the information and push it to the hash collector, denoted with `_`. Then return that node and go on with iteration of the given path.

At the and of the path use `lastItemData` for the wanted object.

```js
var list = [{ lastItemData: { data: "root" }, path: ["Root"] }, { lastItemData: { data: "level2_Summer" }, path: ["Root", "Level2_Summer"] }, { lastItemData: { data: "Level3_Monday" }, path: ["Root", "Level2_Winter", "Level3_Monday"] }, { lastItemData: { data: "Level4_Morning" }, path: ["Root", "Level2_Spring", "Level3_Tuesday", "Level4_Morning"] }, { lastItemData: { data: "Level3_Sunday" }, path: ["Root", "Level2_Autumn", "Level3_Sunday"] }],
    tree = function (array) {
        var result = [],
            hash = { _: { Items: result } };

        array.forEach(function (object) {
            object.path.reduce(function (o, p) {
                if (!o[p]) {
                    o[p] = { _: { text: p, Items: [] } };
                    o._.Items.push(o[p]._);
                }
                return o[p];
            }, hash)._.lastItemData = object.lastItemData;
        });
        return result;
    }(list);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Thank you, Nina! I would never have found such a solution. I'm gonna try this right now.